# Indexer out of bounds when using Pandas apply

Tags: pandas, apply, series, index-error

I am having an issue with the following code which uses pandas apply through a function that returns multiple values in a series...

```
    def make_tonic(title):
         *** function is here ****

         return pd.Series([tonic_chord, Supertonic_chord, Mediant_chord, Subdominant_chord, Dominant_chord, Submediant_chord, Leading_tone_chord, 
    tonic, Supertonic, Mediant, Subdominant, Dominant, Submediant, Leading_tone], 
    
      index = ['Tonic', 'Supertonic', 'Mediant', 'Subdominant', 'Dominant', 'Submediant', 'Leading Tone', 
               'Tonic Notes', 'Supertonic Notes', 'Mediant Notes', 'Subdominant Notes', 
               'Dominant Notes', 'Submediant Notes', 'Leading Tone Notes'])





full_scales_2[['Tonic', 'Supertonic', 'Mediant', 'Subdominant', 'Dominant', 'Submediant', 'Leading Tone', 
               'Tonic Notes', 'Supertonic Notes', 'Mediant Notes', 'Subdominant Notes', 
               'Dominant Notes', 'Submediant Notes', 'Leading Tone Notes']] = full_scales_2['Scale Notes'].apply(make_tonic)
```

And I get the following error:

**" IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds"**

Comment: Got the same error, very strange!!! Did you find the reason for this behaviour?